# React validating whether one of the input fields are been entered

Tags: validation, reactjs, input

I have a scenario where I have to validate whether one of the input fields have values entered.

In the OnBlur Event of each input field I get the value and set in the state, and in the mean time I check whether there is values in one of those input boxes and set the inputIsReq state. And I use that inputIsReq in the required attribute in each text field. After this change my page loads really slow, and the validations doesn't happen too. Any idea to fix this ?

Comment: first of all this code you have provided will not work at all... 
1. `render() {`  not `render {`
2. it will throw Syntax error `Syntax error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag` 
Please fix the obvious errors first.

Comment: Oops that was a mistake by accident, was altering my actual code. corrected it right now. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: now better ;) but still you have to return one node (`Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag`) from render() function

Comment: Do you have any idea why this issue is still happening?

Comment: I did some logic changes as well, but im still getting the same issue :(

Comment: React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance and this.state may be updated asynchronously, so you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state - this is a theretical part :) I will try to find solution for you and post answer to the question soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145370/discussion-between-anna-and-grzegorz-motyl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running slow because you are calling the method changeInputValue instead of passing it as a callback.

this will call changeInputValue:

wrong:
`onBlur={this.changeInputValue("input_4_value", this)}`

correct:
`onBlur={() => this.changeInputValue("input_4_value", this)}`

Abowe example will pass changeInputValue as a callback.

you can also 
`onBlur={changeInputValue}` but then you can't pass any params to callback

You were calling changeInputValue in a loop since it have changed the state and then component was re rendered and so on... This was also producing the warning in a console

> warning.js:36 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing
>   state transition (such as within render or another component's
>   constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved
>   to componentWillMount.